# Query joining in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries like:

```
SELECT PC_COMP_CODE,
    PC_SL_LDGR_CODE,
    PC_SL_ACNO ACCOUNT,
    COUNT(PC_CHEQUE_NO) CHQS,
    SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, PC_AMOUNT)) CHQ_AMT
                     FROM  GLAS_PDC_CHEQUES 
                     WHERE  PC_COMP_CODE  = '1'
                     AND PC_DISCD  IS NULL
                    GROUP BY PC_SL_LDGR_CODE,
             PC_SL_ACNO ,PC_COMP_CODE
                      ORDER BY PC_SL_ACNO 

--------------------------------------------------

  SELECT COAD_PTY_FULL_NAME,PC_COMP_CODE, PC_SL_LDGR_CODE, PC_SL_ACNO, PC_DEPT_NO, PC_DOC_TYPE, PC_CHEQUE_NO, PC_BANK_AC_NO  FROM GLAS_PTY_ADDRESS,GLAS_SBLGR_MASTERS,GLAS_PDC_CHEQUES WHERE
  COAD_COMP_CODE = '1' AND SLMA_COMP_CODE = COAD_COMP_CODE AND SLMA_ADDR_ID = COAD_ADDR_ID
  AND SLMA_LDGRCTL_CODE = PC_SL_LDGR_CODE AND PC_COMP_CODE=SLMA_COMP_CODE
  AND SLMA_ACNO = PC_SL_ACNO 
  AND SLMA_LDGRCTL_YEAR = DBO.GLAS_VALIDATIONS_GET_OPEN_YEAR(PC_COMP_CODE)
```

---

If I execute first query alone I get 5 records...

If I join the above two query like:

```
SELECT
PC_COMP_CODE,
    PC_SL_LDGR_CODE,
    PC_SL_ACNO ACCOUNT,
    COUNT(PC_CHEQUE_NO) CHQS,
    SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, PC_AMOUNT)) CHQ_AMT,
COAD_PTY_FULL_NAME
 FROM  GLAS_PDC_CHEQUES
 LEFT OUTER JOIN   GLAS_SBLGR_MASTERS
ON( SLMA_COMP_CODE=PC_COMP_CODE AND
SLMA_LDGRCTL_CODE = PC_SL_LDGR_CODE AND SLMA_ACNO = PC_SL_ACNO )
LEFT OUTER JOIN GLAS_PTY_ADDRESS ON( SLMA_COMP_CODE = COAD_COMP_CODE AND SLMA_ADDR_ID = COAD_ADDR_ID)

 WHERE  PC_COMP_CODE  = '1'
  AND PC_DISCD  IS NULL   AND SLMA_LDGRCTL_YEAR = DBO.GLAS_VALIDATIONS_GET_OPEN_YEAR(PC_COMP_CODE)
 GROUP BY PC_SL_LDGR_CODE,
    PC_SL_ACNO ,PC_COMP_CODE,COAD_PTY_FULL_NAME
 ORDER BY PC_SL_ACNO
```

then I just get 2 records....

I need that  5 records to display after join.....
How can I do it?

Comment: Mitch: don't look *directly* **at** the query! :-)

Comment: I think this is rare, Mitch, but LLOL. _(literally)_

Answer (score 1):

I grepped all the fields in the first query to make it more readable and more likely that someone can make sense of things. Unfortunately, I gave up at that point.

Results below, but for what its worth, I'll take a shot in the dark and say that you want to join with a [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).

```
SELECT id, first_name, account, COUNT(pants) pants, SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, cost)) amount  
FROM table1  
WHERE id = '1' AND discount IS NULL GROUP BY first_name, account ,id  
ORDER BY account

SELECT full_name,id, first_name, account, department, coffee_pref, pants, acct_no  
FROM table2,table3,table1  
WHERE secret_code = '1'  
  AND public_code = secret_code  
  AND addr_id = phone_id  
  AND nickname = first_name  
  AND id=public_code  
  AND movie_rating = account  
  AND album_year = DBO.get_random_year(id)
```

Comment: Domnic, the problem is that nobody can read your query with obscure names in all capital letters, much less make sense of it.

Again, are you trying to get the 5 results from the 1st query and the 2 from the second query all together (7 results, total)?

Comment: no if i execute first query i got 5 records...
if i execute last query i just got only 2 records ...
i should get hat same 5 records when i execute the last query.........

Comment: There are 3 queries here, right, and the third is supposedly a join on the first two? Doesn't the addition of the second query to the first cause those 5 results to be further filtered down to 2? The additional `WHERE` clause constraints is disqualifying 3 out of 5. Go through those 3 and compare their values to the constraints (if that is even possible), to see why they are getting excluded.